# Using power series to evaluate $\int x^2\sin(x^2)dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

Since I know the series of $\sin(x^2)$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}$$ then do I multiply $x^2$ into this to get $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{4n+4}}{(2n+1)!}$$ and then integrate the infinite series? 
(is my second step valid and am i on the right path?)

Comment: Looks reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that the radius of convergence is infinite, you then obtain
$$
\int_0^xt^2\sin(t^2)\:dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\int_0^xt^{4n+4}dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{4n+5}}{(2n+1)!(4n+5)}.
$$

Comment: thank you! that was very helpful